# How to convert Markdown + CSS -> PDF?

Tags: css, pdf, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a Markdown file into a PDF. I'm looking for only two things:

- A way to easily change the style of the pdf (for example with a CSS file)
- A syntax highlighter for code blocks

What tools can I use for that? I tried Pandoc, but it uses Latex for the formatting which is not easy to use.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a "rendered HTML to PDF" solution, not a Markdown to PDF solution. For the record, HTML -> PDF rarely (never!) works out as well as LaTeX.

Comment: Related: [SuperUser: How Can I Convert Github-Flavored Markdown To A PDF](https://superuser.com/q/689056/425838).

Answer (score 28):

Pandoc can convert your Markdown to HTML, but the styling/layout is a different topic. If you want to produce a PDF but use CSS for styling, you need something that can interpret CSS. That is either use a browser and print to PDF, pay for [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) or try [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (see also [print-css.rocks](https://print-css.rocks)). Btw, pandoc can also use `wkhtmltopdf` now:

```
pandoc -t html --css mystyles.css input.md -o output.pdf
```

But I suspect if you want a beautifully-typeset PDF for free you'll have to learn LaTeX or [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/) which is a modern and more self-contained replacement for LaTeX, both can be used with pandoc. See [creating a PDF with pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf).

You can also give [PanWriter](https://panwriter.com) a try: a markdown editor I built, where you can inject CSS and export the PDF from the paginated preview.

Comment: I found a good github.css style sheet and used it in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64257218/4561887.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I'm using an R markdown (with the bookdown package) and I can't render this file to a PDF version because of my style.css. Where should I insert this command "pandoc -t " ? . I appreciate any help on this. Thanks @mb21

Comment: "I suspect if you want a beautifully-typeset PDF for free you'll have to learn LaTeX" — problem is, writing/reading in Markdown is much less painful than in LaTeX. So you would want to write in markdown and interject it with some LaTeX-tags I guess, similar to html-tags? Which I don't think is possible.

Comment: @Hi-Angel yes you can include [raw TeX](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_tex) in pandoc's markdown

Answer (score 8):

### How to convert a markdown .md document to a PDF at the command-line by using `pandoc` and CSS style settings

With the right settings, `pandoc` does a pretty good job, but is still missing the grey background underneath the code blocks which I'd really like it to have :(. Following the lead of [@mb21's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994783/4561887), here's what I came up with for a pretty decent `pandoc` command for GitHub Flavored Markdown (gfm).

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04:

```bash
# Install pandoc and dependencies
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pandoc
sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf  # a dependency to convert HTML To pdf

# Download the github.css CSS style theme
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simov/markdown-viewer/master/themes/github.css

# Convert test.md to test.pdf using the github.css CSS style theme
pandoc -f gfm -t html5 --metadata pagetitle="test.md" --css github.css \
test.md -o test.pdf
```

The `wget` command is to download the github.css GitHub CSS formatting theme file from here: https://github.com/simov/markdown-viewer/tree/master/themes. It is part of the [Markdown Viewer Chrome plugin here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk), which I wrote about [in my other answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/689056/how-can-i-convert-github-flavored-markdown-to-a-pdf/1591372#1591372).

Breakdown of the `pandoc` command from above:

```bash
-f gfm    # from format = Github Flavored Markdown
-t html5  # to format = html5
--metadata pagetitle="test.md"  # html output format (-t html) requires a 
    # mandatory html title, so just set it to the input file name:
    # "test.md"
--css github.css  # use the github.css file as the CSS styling file for
                  # the html output
test.md      # this is the INPUT markdown (Github Flavored Markdown) file
-o test.pdf  # save the OUTPUT PDF as test.pdf
```

Sample markdown file, **test.md:**

````bash
Snippet from my project here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/markdown/github_readme_center_and_align_images.md

## 1.1. Align images left, right, or centered, with NO WORD WRAP:

This:

```html
**Align left:**
<p align="left" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
</p>

**Align center:**
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
</p>

**Align right:**
<p align="right" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
</p>
```

Produces this:

**Align left:**
<p align="left" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
</p>

**Align center:**
<p align="center" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
</p>

**Align right:**
<p align="right" width="100%">
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
</p>

If you'd like to set the text itself to left, center, or right, you can include the text inside the `<p>` element as well, as regular HTML, like this:

```html
<p align="right" width="100%">
    This text is also aligned to the right.<br>
    <img width="33%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJj4x.png"> 
</p>
```
````

Pandoc conversion command from above:

```
pandoc -f gfm -t html5 --metadata pagetitle="test.md" --css github.css \
test.md -o test.pdf
```

Output PDF screenshot:

Not quite as good as [Markdown Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk), as its still missing the grey background under the code blocks (see what that looks like [in my other answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/689056/how-can-i-convert-github-flavored-markdown-to-a-pdf/1591372#1591372)), but it looks pretty good!

[image]

### See also:

1. [my answer] [SuperUser: How Can I Convert Github-Flavored Markdown To A PDF](https://superuser.com/questions/689056/how-can-i-convert-github-flavored-markdown-to-a-pdf/1591372#1591372)

Comment: btw. the next release of pandoc will also contain [this default CSS](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/templates/styles.html)...

Answer (score 4):

There is really nice and simple tool for browsing Markdown documents which additionally supports export to PDF features:

[GFMS - Github Flavored Markdown Server](https://github.com/pawel-wiejacha/gfms)

It's simple and lightweight (no configuration needed) HTTP server you can start in any directory containing markdown files to browse them.

Features:

- full GFM Markdown support
- source code syntax highlighting
- browsing files and directories
- nice looking output (and configurable CSS style sheets)
- export to PDF (best-looking markdown-to-pdf output I've ever seen)

`gfms -p 8888`

`wget "http://localhost:8888/file.md?pdf" -O file.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gh-md-to-html](https://github.com/phseiff/github-flavored-markdown-to-html) for this, which is a command line tool that does exactly what you want (full disclosure: I'm the author).

You can install it by [installing `wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) and by then using

```
pip3 install gh-md-to-html[pdf_export]
```

And then use

```
gh-md-to-html path_to_your_file.md -p <name>.pdf -c path_to_your_css.html
```

Let's dissect what the individual parts of this command do:

- The `-p` option declares under which file name to save the resulting pdf file; the "`<name>`" is automatically replaced with the name of your input file.
- The `-c` option is a path to a `html`-file which contains css within `<style>`-tags, which will be embedded into the resulting html file before said file is converted to pdf.

Under to hood, `gh-md-to-html` converts the file to html and then to pdf using `wkhtmltopdf`, as the name suggests.

The resulting pdf file is, in any case, styled similar to how GitHub styles their README files; if you want to disable that so you can dictate the styling as a whole using you custom css, you can supply the option `-s false` to the command, which disables the default styling.
Code blocks are properly syntax highlighted in both cases, though.

The conversion process is done partially online (using GitHub's markdown REST API); in case you don't want that, you can use `pip3 install gh-md-to-html[offline_conversion]` and then run `gh-md-to-html` with the `-o OFFLINE` option.

Answer (score 0):

To a certain extent, I'd suggest just learning the basic latex formatting you need - it removes a layer of interpretation by the renderer.

However, pandoc does support html input, so in theory, you could export markdown->html(with custom css), then call pandoc again to convert to html. I don't know if (or how much) of the formatting would be saved - css can be *really* complicated to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same requirement. While **pandoc** works well, I don't really like the styling and it is very complex to download a CSS and make it work with that. Maybe I am just too lazy!

Instead, here is a quick hack. You can create your markdown on the **jupyter notebook** and just download that as PDF. Yes, it requires you to download a few libraries but I love the font and styling.

Another simpler way would be to click on `File` -> `Print Preview` from your jupyter notebook and print that as a PDF.

Comment: You can also explore the `Download as` menu from your jupyter notebook for further customizations. For eg: download as HTML and make modifications to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to customize the appearance of elements in a PDF file if you convert md -> pdf using the Python [markdown-pdf module](https://github.com/vb64/markdown-pdf).

For example, like this:

```
pip install markdown-pdf

from markdown_pdf import MarkdownPdf, Section

pdf = MarkdownPdf()

# header is centered using CSS
pdf.add_section(
  Section("# Head1\n\nbody\n"),
  user_css="h1 {text-align:center;}"
)

pdf.save("output.pdf")
```

Syntax highlighting cannot be done using this method (yet).