# Header style in R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am writing a report in R markdown (using pdflatex to convert it into pdf) and I am trying to set the style of the different headers (color, size, interline before and after).
I am using this formalisation :
#H1
##H2
###H3
I have the basics of Markdown and LaTeX but I'm far to be an expert. Is there a way to do it without creating a LaTeX template ? For exemple with some YAML code in the head of the document ?
Mine for now :

```
---
title: "Guide"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
    highlight: tango
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
documentclass: report
---
```

Or by changing the R options ?

````
```{r set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
options(some stuff)
```
````

I've found some indications while searching that suggest it may be possible, but I could'nt manage to find any understandable exemple ...
Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to do any LaTeX, you could add your own CSS (see [documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#custom_css)) and set it that way, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30447045/2573061).

You would then need to do: [How to convert Markdown + CSS -> PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825317/how-to-convert-markdown-css-pdf)

However, your results may not be as faithfully rendered as if you create a LaTeX template.